# How do I determine whether a file is in use?

Tags: file, vbscript, batch-file

How can I determine whether a file is in use via VBScript or a batch file?  It can be a separate utility.

I've had a look at [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) but sometimes the handles don't line up with filenames, e.g. some DLLs, and it doesn't do partial searches (though I could presumably use some of the text processing utils on its full output to handle that side of things).

Comment: Is this "in use by any other process", or "in use by a specific process", i.e. one you control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have ended up using is [ListDLLs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx).  Running "listdlls -d  | find /c "pid" > temp.txt" and then testing whether there's any data in temp.txt seems to determine whether or not a file is in use successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply attempt to do whatever you want to do to the file, and report an error if it fails with a sharing violation?

"It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission." - Grace Hopper

Or if you want to know in advance whether an attempt to do something destructive will succeed, you could attempt to do something non-destructive that requires the same permissions.  So if you want to know whether you can overwrite a file, try to open it for appending but don't write anything.

Whatever you do, you'll need to beware race conditions - what if someone else opens the file between your test and your actual operation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
echo.N|copy /-y NUL "%~1">NUL
if not errorlevel 1 echo not in use
if errorlevel 1 echo in use
```

Credit: [DosTips.com :IsFileOpen](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Function.IsFileOpen)

Comment: This definitely did not work.  It was reporting everything as "not in use".

Comment: There are several "file open" types; I think this method just work for exclusive locks, as I tested with an `Access LDB` file and it reported "in use"; I'm running Windows 2008